# Obfuscated apk code crash log

Tags: android, apk

I'am working with a large android project,very large,and we obfuscate our code when we release our apk to market,now the trouble is:
when our application crashed,actually，our application would post the crash log to our service,but the crash log make no mean,because we have obfuscated it already,we got infomation like this:a(),b(Unknown Source),c()....
so,how to deal with it?how to geting a readable crash log in obfuscate apk?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you obfuscate your code, a file called `mapping.txt` is generated. This file describes the mapping between your original symbols and their obfuscated versions.

If you save this file for your public builds, you can use the [`retrace`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#decode-stack-trace) tool to deobfuscate any stack traces you receive from crashes, thereby making them useable for fixing bugs! You invoke the tool as follows:

```
retrace.sh -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt
```

Comment: Hey,as you said,I got a crash dump: at com.ifreetalk.ftalk.activity.MainChatBarActivity.JudgeSameCityInvald(Unknown Source)
                                                     initView
                                                     setChannelListView
                                                     refreshChannelListView
                                                     refreshTopMsg
                                                     access$10 access$102                                                                                                  which method course crash?